# ArgumentError in Orders#new , wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, and I am following the book pragmatic agile. When I am considering the customer details I am facing this sort of error...

```
  wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

And my code in views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
</div>
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
                             :prompt => 'select a payment method' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
```

And I gave the arguments in app/model/order.rb

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :address, :name, :pay_type
    PAYMENT_TYPES = [ 'Check', 'Credit card', 'Purchase order' ]

 end
```

can I get any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
</div>
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
   <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
                         :prompt => 'select a payment method' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
```

Notice it should be "select"

Comment: I did that but, I did not get it. You mean to say put the entire select statement in double quotes? I have done the same thing..

Comment: No, he means you should be using `f.select` where your code uses `f.text_field`.

Comment: Oh ya sorry, I got it now!